# How to get async data without reloading whole app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying when the user clicks on bottomTabNavigator the component screen will reload. I mean in my first component screen "AnotherA.js", I am using textinput which store user entered data in async storage and in another component "AnotherB.js" I am using get() of async storage to show my stored data on the screen. I am able to see the stored data the first time while reloading the whole app.

I am trying to get data without reloading, the whole app, by navigating with bottomTabNavigator it displays immediately.

```
//App.js

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs';
import { TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import AnotherA from './AnotherA';
import AnotherB from './AnotherB';

const AppNavigator = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    AnotherA: { screen: AnotherA },
    AnotherB: { screen: AnotherB }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AnotherA',
    activeColor: '#f0edf6',
    inactiveColor: '#3e2465',
    barStyle: { backgroundColor: '#694fad' },
    pressColor: 'pink',
  },
  {
    //tabBarComponent: createMaterialBottomTabNavigator /* or TabBarTop */,
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    defaultnavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarOnPress: (scene, jumpToIndex) => {
        console.log('onPress:', scene.route);
        jumpToIndex(scene.index);

      },
    }),

  }
);
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
export default AppContainer;
```

//AnotherA.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, AsyncStorage, View, Text, Button, TextInput, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableHighlight, Linking } from 'react-native';
import styles from './styles';

export default class AnotherA extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            myKey: '',
            text1: '',

        }
    }

    async getKey() {
        try {
            //const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:key');
            const key = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:key');

            this.setState({
                myKey: key,
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error retrieving data" + error);
        }
    }

    async saveKey(text1) {
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('@MySuperStore:key', text1);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error saving data" + error);
        }
    }

    async resetKey() {
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.removeItem('@MySuperStore:key');
            const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:key');
            this.setState({
                myKey: value,
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error resetting data" + error);
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getKey();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TextInput
                    placeholder="Enter Data"
                    value={this.state.myKey}
                    onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({ text1: value })}
                    multiline={true}
                />
                <Button
                    onPress={() => this.saveKey(this.state.text1)}
                    title="Save"
                />
                <Button
                    //style={styles.formButton}
                    onPress={this.resetKey.bind(this)}
                    title="Reset"
                    color="#f44336"
                    accessibilityLabel="Reset"
                />
                </View>
        )
    }
}
```

//AnotherB.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, AsyncStorage, View, Text, Button, TextInput, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableHighlight, Linking } from 'react-native';
import styles from './styles';

export default class AnotherB extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            myKey: '',
            text1: '',

        }
    }

    async getKey() {
        try {
            //const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:key');
            const key = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:key');

            this.setState({
                myKey: key,
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error retrieving data" + error);
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getKey();
    }

    render() {
        //const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        //const { newValue, height } = this.state;
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>{this.state.myKey}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

**Please suggest, I am new to React-Native.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are retrieving the value from `AsyncStorage` when the component mounts. Unfortunately that isn't going to load the value on the screen when you switch tabs. What you need to do is subscribe to [updates](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle) to navigation lifecycle.

It is fairly straight forward to do. There are four lifecycle events that you can subscribe to. You can choose which of them that you want to subscribe to.

> - `willFocus` - the screen will focus
> - `didFocus` - the screen focused (if there was a transition, the transition completed)
> - `willBlur` - the screen will be unfocused
> - `didBlur` - the screen unfocused (if there was a transition, the transition completed)

You subscribe to the events when the component mounts and then unsubscribe from them when it unmounts. So when the event you have subscribed to happens, it will call the function that you have put into the subscriber's callback.

So you can do something like this in you `AnotherB.js`:

```
componentDidMount() {
    // subscribe to the event that we want, in this case 'willFocus'
    // when the screen is about to focus it will call this.getKey
    this.willFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', this.getKey);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    // unsubscribe to the event 
    this.willFocusSubscription.remove();
}

getKey = async () => { // update this to an arrow function so that we can still access this, otherwise we'll get an error trying to setState.
    try {
        const key = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:key');
        this.setState({
            myKey: key,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error retrieving data" + error);
    }
}
```

Here is a quick snack that I created showing it working, https://snack.expo.io/@andypandy/navigation-life-cycle-with-asyncstorage

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add then after `getItem`

```
AsyncStorage.getItem("@MySuperStore:key").then((value) => {
    this.setState({
        myKey: value,
    });
})
.then(res => {
    //do something else
});
```

Comment: Sorry! but nothing happens.

Comment: Put the above code in componentDidMount() of AnotherB.js