# Frontend showing white blank space; Messages updated only after refresh; textoverflow at the middle of the text

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Hi I met a few problems while working on front end wonder if anyone have similar problem / able to give some tips. Here is the link to my frontend:
https://replit.com/@KintQ/waveportal-starter-project#src/App.jsx

[White Blank Space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HO4Cf.png)

[textoverflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hIOp.png)

**1. Webpage having blank space**

Before connecting wallet, the webpage were showing blank white space below the button. After connecting however there is no issue on the display.

**2. getAllWaves messages need to refresh page to show**

After connecting wallet, i was wanting to let all the messages left by users to appear without needing to refresh the page. How should i go about with that ?

**3. textoverflow in the middle!**

My current design looks like the picture shown here. But what i want was smtg like: "0x00...9999". Just wondering how to make it couldnt wrap my head around it!

Comment: 1. try height: 100vh for mainContainer class. 2. try async data (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54764562/how-to-get-async-data-without-reloading-whole-app). 3. try text-overflow css or customer javascript function (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831552/ellipsis-in-the-middle-of-a-text-mac-style)

Comment: @Nayan Hi Ive tried your suggestion (1) which is height: 100vh. It did solved the white blank space issue. However after i connecting the wallet and the page suppose to update a log of messages it fill the whole web page with the message.

Since the messages are not present before clicking button. How can I make sure after the action it appears, the messages wont fill up the entire page... Thank you for your answering anyway!